# Can't copy paste folder, connection lost

Tags: scp

I want to transfer a folder to another folder.

Below is my command

```
scp /home/web/domains/site.com/public_html/sql/months root@54.84.145.22:/home/web/domains/site.com/public_html/sql/months2
```

While I entered the command above, error message appeared:

```
ssh: connect to host 54.84.145.22 port 22:Connecton refused
```

My root login port is ***9311***

Why was the error showing and the port showing in error is ***22*** not ***9311***?

PS: I am using SSH. Linux server.

Comment: It seems that the ssh server might not be running or it's listening to a different port. First check sshd is running on the remote host

Comment: How do I check whether the sshd is running on the remote host or not? @vembutech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running ssh on non-sandard port, you need to specify it using `-P` option. Also if you want to sopy folder, you need to do it with `-r` option, so it will dive into subdirectories.

```
scp -r -P 9311 /home/web/domains/site.com/public_html/sql/months \
  root@54.84.145.22:/home/web/domains/site.com/public_html/sql/months2
```

To make sure service is running on the remote server, you can try to ssh directly to that machine using

```
ssh -p 9911 root@54.84.145.22
```

Comment: I insert the 2 commands above and message this appear. The authenticity of host '111.111.11.111 (111.111.11.111)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is fd:fd:d4:f9:77:fe:73:84:e1:55:00:ad:d6:6d:22:fe.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
@Jakuje

Comment: if you have correct IP, it means there is sshd server running and if you have password, you should be able to copy the folder.